# PostgreSQL query for returning sorted table entries by one-to-many children count

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `posts` which has a one-to-many relationship with `comments`.

Table Posts

```
id | text
---------
1  | "foo"
2  | "bar"
3  | "baz"
```

Table Comments

```
id | post_id | text
-------------------
1  | 2       | "lorem"
2  | 2       | "ipsum"
3  | 3       | "dolor"
```

I want to compose a query that will return all the `posts` entries sorted by highest to lowest of the related `comments` count

So my output should be:

Table Posts

```
id | text
---------
2  | "bar"    (2 Total comments)
3  | "baz"    (1 Total comments)
1  | "foo"    (0 Total comments)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select p.id, min(p.text) as text
from posts p left outer join comments c on c.post_id = p.id
group by p.id
order by count(c.post_id) desc;
```

This one might not be portable or fully supported:

```
select * from posts p
order by (select count(*) from comments c where c.post_id = p.id) desc;
```

And I tested this one as well for fun:

```
select distinct on (count(c.post_id) over (partition by p.id), p.id) p.id, p.text
from posts p left outer join comments c on c.post_id = p.id
order by count(c.post_id) over (partition by p.id) desc, p.id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6e4a54dd00cfe45267b678d912654c25

Comment: This works, thanks! However, instead of using `select p.id, min(p.text) as text` I tried `select *` and this returns me an error with `ERROR:  column "c.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select *`. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Because when using groups you can no longer return all columns unaggregated. The second query would work for that though.